# Magento 2 Reorder Button - How to ignore out of stock item

Tags: magento2, reorder

The method responsible for reordering is `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::_canReorder()`. The method `_canReorder` is called by `Mage_Sales_Model_Order::canReorder()`. This is actually called to see if you can reorder. I understood that part.

I know that the reorder button doesn't show up when an item is out of stock. How can I make ignore this condition and allow customer to reorder by excluding the out of stock item?

The `_canReorder` function looks like this:

```
 protected function _canReorder($ignoreSalable = false)
{
    if ($this->canUnhold() || $this->isPaymentReview()) {
        return false;
    }

    if ($this->getActionFlag(self::ACTION_FLAG_REORDER) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $products = [];
    $itemsCollection = $this->getItemsCollection();
    foreach ($itemsCollection as $item) {
        $products[] = $item->getProductId();
    }

    if (!empty($products)) {
        $productsCollection = $this->productListFactory->create()
            ->setStoreId($this->getStoreId())
            ->addIdFilter($products)
            ->addAttributeToSelect('status')
            ->load();

        foreach ($itemsCollection as $item) {
            $product = $productsCollection->getItemById($item->getProductId());
            if (!$product) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!$ignoreSalable && !$product->isSalable()) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

Where is the part that detects "out of stock" item and how can I add logic to exclude out of stock item from reordering cart?

I'm new to Magento, so any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the above code, that things check using this code.

```
if (!$ignoreSalable && !$product->isSalable()) {
                return false;
}
```

Comment: so "isSalable" checks product’s “status”, stock availability. In my case, if for example, I would like the reorder button to always appear, so the customer can just click the "reorder" button. Right now, what it is doing is that, if an order history X has n items. if 1 item out of the n items is out-of-stock, the reorder button doesn't appear. I'm wondering how can I make the reorder button to always appear, so when a customer clicks on the reorder button, it will create the new shopping cart with the items that are available. Can I just remove the "isSalable()" from this if statement?

Comment: And would it affect how the code works? Thanks in advance. I'm still new to Magento, so any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, it affect the magento default functionality, because your requirement is to modify that one.

Comment: How would it affect it? If I remove isSalable, the code won't check the product status anymore and will always make the "reorder button" to always show up?

Comment: Hello @DhirenVasoya, is their any way we can ignore the OOS item & show the items which are in stock in reorder page ?
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/348456/magento-2-reorder-button-in-magento-admin-doesnt-work-when-an-item-is-oos

Answer (score 0):

isSalable will always going to check the stock availability of the product. What you can actually do is.
Override template files
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/recent.phtml`
`vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml`

Comment out the canReorder check in those files.

`<?php //if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>` 
...

`<?php //endif ?>`

Comment: If I comment that out, how can it successfully create a new order and ignore the out of stock items?

Comment: Don't comment the whole section, comment only if statement. Let the button be shown regardless if the product in the order is saleable or not.

Comment: how would it handle the out-of-stock item if I comment that if statement?

Comment: Backend code will automatically handle that.