# Magento 2 : Reorder button in Magento Admin doesn't work when an item is OOS

Tags: magento2

I am working on Magento 2.4.2.

I am getting a "This product is out of stock." error on re-order from admin.

As Only a couple of the items are Out of Stock at the moment (Item one & Item two) from Total 5 items (the other three items are in stock) in order but no items are added to the new order and there's an error message that says "This product is out of stock." (without indicating which item is out of stock).

Steps to recreate:

1. Login to Magento admin
2. Sales > Orders
3. Search for order
4. Click into order
5. Click "Reorder" on the top right of the page

**Expected:** The new order should have all the in-stock items from the original order added.

Is there any way it can be done?

Comment: File - /Magento2/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote.php Commenting - //throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__(implode("\n", $errors))); on 1711 fixed the issue, but when i click order place , order gets placed even if product is out of stock.

Comment: any thoughts on this ?